# Combining linux shell sed command

Tags: shell, sed

I had three sed commands which are

```
sed 's/"//g'
sed 's/  *//g'
echo $1 | sed 's/.*'$2':\([^,}]*\).*/\1/'
```

How can I combine the above three sed commands together?

Comment: could you provide a sample input along with expected output?

Comment: Use `sed -e`: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33157/what-is-the-purpose-of-e-in-sed-command

Comment: and that's what happens when you try to meld copy-pasted code snippets without knowing what the hell are you doing.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine multiple commands using `-e`

**For example :**

```
sed -e 'command' -e 'command'
```

Hope this helps .

Answer (score 1):

To join  `sed` command, you can also use `;` without the  `-e` like this:

```
sed 'code;code;code' file
```

eks:

```
sed 's/"//g;s/  *//g' file
```